# jQuery interupt event ( wait for some time)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using this code to search by ajax and jquery:

```
// this is the id of the submit button
$("form#search_form input#key").keyup(function() {
    if ( $(this).val().length >=2 ){


    var url = base_url()+"welcome/search2"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: { 'key':$("#key").val() }, // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               //alert(data); // show response from the php script.
               $('#livesearch').html(data); 
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    }
    else $("#fonded2").hide();
});
```

but there is a problem when the user is writing fast.
is there any way to interupt searching when the user enter a new letter after 500ms

Comment: Maybe you can validate the length of the $('#key').val(); and when you consider that the length is considerable, you can do the ajax post, btw... what are you trying to achieve with all this? maybe there is a plugin on the net

Comment: With a timer it can do the work! ------

var ajaxReq = setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: { 'key':$("#key").val() }, // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               //alert(data); // show response from the php script.
               $('#livesearch').html(data); 
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    },500);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var timer;

$("form#search_form input#key").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which==13) return false; // avoid executing form.
    clearTimeout(timer);
    if ( this.value.length >=2 ){
        var url = base_url()+"welcome/search2";

        timer=setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: { 'key':$("#key").val() },
                success: function(data) {
                    //alert(data);
                   $('#livesearch').html(data); 
               }
           });
        }, 500);
    }else{
       $("#fonded2").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should wait until the input is blurred. I imagine this is the best way considering [Google waits for the blur event to be called](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&hl=en) on their sign up page for the username field.